# $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").trigger('click'); goes in infinite loop

Tags: jquery

```
$.post(url, data, function(resp) {
    if (resp.error) {
        ...
    }
    else {
        $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").trigger('click');
    }
},"json");
}
```

I need to close the dialog in else loop but:

```
$('#customAssignmentDialog').dialog('close');
```

Does not close the dialog so I tried:

`$(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").trigger('click');`

But it goes in to an infinite loop. Any ideas?*emphasized text*

Comment: keep an "id" for the dialog box and then close trigger the click using the id. something like `$("#id").click();`

Comment: strange things.... it should work... see http://jsfiddle.net/fYBMQ/1/ it may help to also post the contents of updateValidationMessage function... can it be that this function manipulates the dialog also?

Comment: please show your HTML so we can try to figure why `.dialog('close')` doesn't work.

Comment: I have delete button which calls above javascript function. It deletes the record but does not close the window. I have copied that code above.

Answer (score 0):

Got it...

```
$('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close:visible').click()
```

Comment: you really should use the `.dialog('close')` method - it would be better to figure out why that doesn't work than to use a hack with event triggers.

Comment: I used it but it the dialog stays on the page. I also checked the condition after the loop if (#abc).dialog('open') then (#abc).dialog('close') but that goes in infinite loop. Also tried with do while but couldn't get the solution.

Comment: you need to show more code then, including any event handlers you have for dialog open/close events.

Comment: yup.. you were right ... there was issue with foreign key constraint in database while deleting the recode & that is why it was not working ... now .dialog('close') works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here a working example, hope this helps:

```
<div id="dialog-message" title="Close Example">
    <span class="dialog-descr">
        Click Create to close the widget.
    </span>           
</div>  

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        var closeWidget = function(){
            $("#dialog-message").dialog('close');
        }

        $("#dialog-message").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            draggable: false,
            resizable: false,
            position: {my: "center top", at: "center top"},
            show: 'blind',
            hide: 'blind',
            width: 400,
            dialogClass: 'ui-dialog-osx',
            buttons: {
                "Create": closeWidget,
                "Annulla": function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });         

    });
</script>
```